# função para exibir mais itens em uma <ul>

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso que apenas 5 itens sejam mostrados e caso o usuário queira ver mais itens ele precisa clicar no botão **'ver mais'** e será exibido mais 5 itens. Lembrando q não existe quantidade limite de itens.

```html
<ul class="list">
  <a href="loja1">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 1</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="loja2">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 2</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="loja3">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 3</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="loja4">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 4</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="loja5">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 5</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="loja6">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 6</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="loja7">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 7</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="loja8">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 8</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a href="loja9">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 9</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
</ul>
```

Comment: Adicione os valores em um `array` e depois faça um `for` de `n` até 4 e armazene o número maior em uma variável global. Você pode inicializar `n = 0`

Comment: dá pra definir uma altura inicial para a lista e ocultar o restante com overflow hidden, e conforme o usuario clicar ele aumenta a altura

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

Criei uma classe `.blocos` para usar em vez de `href`.

---

Com jQuery seria bem mais fácil, mas segue em JS puro.

Primeiro é ocultar todas as `<a>` que possuem <s>href="loja.."</s> a classe `.blocos` no CSS:

```
.blocos{
   display: none;
}
```

Depois a ideia é definir os itens por vez numa variável que chamei de `itens = 5;` e mostrar os 5 primeiros itens no carregamento da página. Mas antes adicionei um botão <kbd>Ver mais...</kbd> no final.

Depois é só fazer *loops* mostrando apenas os itens invisíveis dentro do limite da variável `itens` cada vez que o botão <kbd>Ver mais...</kbd> for clicado:

```js
var itens = 5;
var lojas = document.querySelectorAll(".blocos");
for(var x=0; x<itens; x++){
   lojas[x].style.display = "block";
}

document.querySelector("#vermais").addEventListener("click", function(){

   var visiveis = document.querySelectorAll(".blocos");
   var conta = 0;
   for(var x=0; x<visiveis.length; x++){
      if(visiveis[x].style.display == "block") conta++;
   }

   var limite = conta+itens > lojas.length-1 ? lojas.length : conta+itens;

   for(var x=conta; x<limite; x++){
      lojas[x].style.display = "block";
   }
   
   // Aqui eu faço o botão desaparecer quando não tiver mais nada pra mostrar
   if(lojas.length - conta < itens) document.querySelector("#vermais").outerHTML = '';
});
```

```css
.blocos{
   display: none;
}

#vermais{
   margin-top: 15px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <a class="blocos" href="loja1">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 1</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja2">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 2</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja3">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 3</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja4">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 4</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja5">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 5</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja6">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 6</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja7">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 7</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja8">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 8</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja9">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 9</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja10">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 10</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja11">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 11</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja12">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 12</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <a class="blocos" href="loja13">
    <li>
      <img src="images/icon.jpg" title="" alt="" />
      <section class="list-left">
        <h5 class="title">Loja 13</h5>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Telefone :</span>
        <span class="catpath">(99) 9999-9999</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-left">
        <span class="catpath1">Endereço :</span>
        <span class="catpath">R blablabla, 222</span>
      </section>
      <section class="list-right">
        <span class="cityname">Sao Paulo-SP</span>
      </section>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </li>
  </a>
  <button id="vermais">Ver mais...</button>
</ul>
```

Comment: gostei do seu código para ocultar todas as li

Comment: cara muito obrigado, exatamente o que preciso.

Comment: Uma pergunta @Dvd, caso tenha que modificar o nome do ul.list a[href*='loja'] e tenha que ser diferente como loja, restaurante, oficina.. como deve ser feito? Me desculpe mais não conheço quase relacionado a scripts.

Comment: @KaueGalvão Neste caso vc pode adicionar uma `class`, fica até mais fácil. Seria: `<a class="blocos" href="loja2">`... aí no JS ficaria: `var lojas = document.querySelectorAll(".blocos");`

Comment: @KaueGalvão E no CSS: `.blocos{   display: none; }`

Comment: Fiz as mudanças que você solicitou, só que agora não aparece mais nada. não é preciso mudar essa linha também @Dvd?    var visiveis = document.querySelectorAll("ul.list a[href*='loja']");

Comment: @KaueGalvão Sim, tudo que era `"ul.list a[href*='loja']` vc vai mudar para a classe que criou

Comment: @KaueGalvão Vou editar a resposta colocando uma classe.

Comment: @KaueGalvão Resposta atualizada. Dá uma olhada, às vezes vc esqueceu de algum detalhe.

Comment: Mano ja descobri o problema, estava utilizando a  **** do filezila, deu problema no arquivo js peço desculpas pelo seu tempo. Ta funcionando certinho vou apagar meu comentário.

Comment: @KaueGalvão Relaxa, não é nenhum incômodo. QQ coisa se eu puder ajudar, é só chamar.

Answer (score 1):

Conforme foi dito no comentário. Você pode inserir seus elementos em um `array`.

E assim no carregamento da pagina mostrar somente os 4 e um link que mostre mais (no caso todos).

**veja o exemplo:**

```js
//esse array irá conter todas as suas li e seus links
array = [];

//como voce disse que pode ser várias, então aqui você irá adicionar quantas forem no array.

//exemplo feito com uma li.
array[0] = "<a href='loja_NOVA'>    <li>      <img src='images/icon.jpg' title='' alt='' />      <section class='list-left'>        <h5 class='title'>loja_NOVA</h5>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Telefone :</span>        <span class='catpath'>(99) 9999-9999</span>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Endereço :</span>        <span class='catpath'>R blablabla, 222</span>      </section>      <section class='list-right'>        <span class='cityname'>Sao Paulo-SP</span>      </section>      <div class='clearfix'></div>    </li>  </a>";

array[1] = "<a href='loja_NOVA'>    <li>      <img src='images/icon.jpg' title='' alt='' />      <section class='list-left'>        <h5 class='title'>loja_NOVA</h5>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Telefone :</span>        <span class='catpath'>(99) 9999-9999</span>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Endereço :</span>        <span class='catpath'>R blablabla, 222</span>      </section>      <section class='list-right'>        <span class='cityname'>Sao Paulo-SP</span>      </section>      <div class='clearfix'></div>    </li>  </a>";

array[2] = "<a href='loja_NOVA'>    <li>      <img src='images/icon.jpg' title='' alt='' />      <section class='list-left'>        <h5 class='title'>loja_NOVA</h5>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Telefone :</span>        <span class='catpath'>(99) 9999-9999</span>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Endereço :</span>        <span class='catpath'>R blablabla, 222</span>      </section>      <section class='list-right'>        <span class='cityname'>Sao Paulo-SP</span>      </section>      <div class='clearfix'></div>    </li>  </a>";

array[3] = "<a href='loja_NOVA'>    <li>      <img src='images/icon.jpg' title='' alt='' />      <section class='list-left'>        <h5 class='title'>loja_NOVA</h5>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Telefone :</span>        <span class='catpath'>(99) 9999-9999</span>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Endereço :</span>        <span class='catpath'>R blablabla, 222</span>      </section>      <section class='list-right'>        <span class='cityname'>Sao Paulo-SP</span>      </section>      <div class='clearfix'></div>    </li>  </a>";

array[4] = "<a href='loja_NOVA'>    <li>      <img src='images/icon.jpg' title='' alt='' />      <section class='list-left'>        <h5 class='title'>loja_NOVA</h5>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Telefone :</span>        <span class='catpath'>(99) 9999-9999</span>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Endereço :</span>        <span class='catpath'>R blablabla, 222</span>      </section>      <section class='list-right'>        <span class='cityname'>Sao Paulo-SP</span>      </section>      <div class='clearfix'></div>    </li>  </a>";

array[5] = "<a href='loja_NOVA'>    <li>      <img src='images/icon.jpg' title='' alt='' />      <section class='list-left'>        <h5 class='title'>loja_NOVA</h5>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Telefone :</span>        <span class='catpath'>(99) 9999-9999</span>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Endereço :</span>        <span class='catpath'>R blablabla, 222</span>      </section>      <section class='list-right'>        <span class='cityname'>Sao Paulo-SP</span>      </section>      <div class='clearfix'></div>    </li>  </a>";

array[6] = "<a href='loja_NOVA'>    <li>      <img src='images/icon.jpg' title='' alt='' />      <section class='list-left'>        <h5 class='title'>loja_NOVA</h5>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Telefone :</span>        <span class='catpath'>(99) 9999-9999</span>      </section>      <section class='list-left'>        <span class='catpath1'>Endereço :</span>        <span class='catpath'>R blablabla, 222</span>      </section>      <section class='list-right'>        <span class='cityname'>Sao Paulo-SP</span>      </section>      <div class='clearfix'></div>    </li>  </a>";


//essa função será chamada no carregar da pagina, e irá mostrar somente os 4 como você falou


window.onload = function() {
quantos = 4;
mybtn = document.getElementById('btnm-o');

mostra_quatro();

};

function mostra_quatro(){

var wrapper = document.getElementById('ul_master');

//pega o conteudo que esta dentro do seu ul

if(quantos == 4){
HTMLTemporario = wrapper.innerHTML;
}else{
HTMLTemporario = '';
}
// vai colocando as strings <a><li> até dar 4.
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) { 
HTMLTemporario = HTMLTemporario+ array[i];
}

// Coloca a nova string(que é o HTML) no DOM
wrapper.innerHTML = HTMLTemporario;

mybtn.innerHTML = 'Mostrar Mais';

}


function mostra_mais(){

if(quantos != 4){
   mostra_quatro();
}else{

var wrapper = document.getElementById('ul_master');
//pega o conteudo que esta dentro do seu ul
HTMLTemporario = wrapper.innerHTML;

// vai colocando as strings <a><li> até dar o fim do array 1 ou 1 milhao.
for (i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { 
HTMLTemporario = HTMLTemporario + array[i];
}

// Coloca a nova string(que é o HTML) no DOM
wrapper.innerHTML = HTMLTemporario;

mybtn.innerHTML = 'Exibir Menos';
quantos = 99;
}
}
```

```html
<ul class="list" id='ul_master'>
  
  
</ul>
<button type='button' onclick='mostra_mais()' id='btnm-o'>mostra mais</button>
```

Comment: Muito bom também seu código, só tenho uma pergunta, após clicar em mostrar menos porque quando eu clico em mostrar mais novamente ele não mostra?

Comment: @KaueGalvão ah é porque eu tinha entendido que seria um mostrar mais, e um mostrar menos, (pode reparar que na minha resposta ele muda o texto do botao). Mas como você ja tem um exemplo do que queria na outra  resposta, entao vou deixar a minha assim como uma resposta alternativa, pode ser? mas se quiser posso colocar o mostrar mais igual o dele

Comment: sua resposta está perfeita, só gostaria de saber se existe a possibilidade de poder clicar várias vezes, por exemplo eu clico em mostrar mais, aí mostra 5 itens, aí clico novamente e mostra mais 5 clico de novo mais 5... Só que ao chegar no final aparecesse a opção mostrar menos. Mais está ótimo esse código muito bom mesmo me ajudou muito mano!!!

Comment: tem como sim, vou fazer nesse esquema! obrigado Kaue! estamos ai pra nos ajudar!